# Summary of validation stays after second submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

NET with C# to create a registration form. After I've submitted a form, my form goes through validation, and should there be any errors, they will be displayed in a panel on a label. However, my problem is, after the first validation, after I press submit once more, the error from the first validation still stays on the form, and the 2nd set of validation errors will just be listed after. How would I go about editing my codes if I want the validation to refresh, but leave behind the correct data in my fields for my users to correct only the incorrect fields for an efficient form submission.  Here's a chunk of code as an example of how I validate one of the fields of my form,

```
  if (teacherName.Length == 0)
        {
            TeacherNamePanel.CssClass = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
            Label span = new Label();
            span.CssClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
            TeacherNamePanel.Controls.Add(span);
            lblWarning.Text += "Please enter the name of teacher-in-charge! <br />";
        }
        else
            TeacherNamePanel.CssClass = "form-group";
```

and the rest of the validation after all input has been entered

```
string msg = "";
        msg = accBLL.processCreateAccount(groupName, password, confirmPassword, school, teacherName, groupName, member1, member2, member3);

        if (msg == "Sucess")
        {
            SuccessPanel.Visible = true;
            lblSuccess.Text = "You have successfully signed up";
            WarningPanel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            SuccessPanel.Visible = false;
            lblWarning.Text += "There has been an error. Please try again!<br />";
            WarningPanel.Visible = true;
        }
```

Here is the panel I use for displaying the validation messages

```
<asp:Panel ID="WarningPanel" CssClass="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" runat="server">
      <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

and below is the panel I keep my input control

```
<asp:Panel ID="TeacherNamePanel" CssClass="form-group has-feedback" runat="server">
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbTeacherName" CssClass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Teacher-in-charge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Are you setting `lblWarning.Text` to blank at any point in your code? Looks like you are just adding and adding text and never resetting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set EnableViewState Property of lblWarning = False. I will infact  advice to set EnableViewState="False" even for lblSuccess Label